# I want to use dates in ui picker view for first component

Tags: ios, uipickerview

I am trying to use dates in picker view for first component. I want to use another component with another array.

Please help me out...Thanks

Comment: Like we can add it from array right, So I want to add the same all dates into array

Answer (score 0):

You will be needing 2 arrays right? Then Declare and populate two arrays to be used in two components as follows:

```
NSArray *firstComponentArray = // populate the first array here
NSArray *secondComponetArray = // populate the second array here

.
.
.

- (NSInteger) numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
   // return the number of components do you need
}

// return the right number of items in picker view delegate: numberOfRowsInComponent
- (NSInteger) pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent(NSInteger)component
{   
   // first component
   if ( component == 0 )
     // return the count of the first array

   // second component  
   else
     //return the count of the second array
}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row   forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
   // first component
   if ( component == 0 )
     // return the content of the first array at index using row


   // second component  
   else
     // return the content of the second array at index using row
}
```